# ASP.NET Identity WebForms and Custom Role Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, identity

I've moved to using ASP.NET Identity for authentication for my WebForms app.  I've got the functionality working the way I want to.  Now I want to add a little wrinkle to the way Role Authorization works but can't figure out where to start.

So in my web.config I have locations set up like this:

```
<location path="Admin">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="Admin1,Admin2" />
            <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

This works with ASP.NET Identity.  However, I want to change it to this:

```
<location path="Admin">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="Admin1,Admin2,feature:Lollipops" />
            <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

So basically the way it would work is that the User would need to have either the Admin1 or Admin2 role, and the "Lollipops" feature.  I've managed to get all the necessary data into the Identity cookie, but I can't figure out for the life of me where to change the Role Authorization.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: Nope.  I rolled my own solution that parses the appropriate web.config section and determines if the user has access.  But whatever authorization that ASP.NET is doing is still being done, mine occurs in an HTTP module.

Comment: So years later I figured this out.  ASP.NET WebForms has an HttpModule named UrlAuthorizationModule that is automatically added.  It is responsible for parsing the location authorization tags and determining access.   OWIN will take its identity and automatically populate HttpContext.Current.User with the OWIN identity.  If you want to expand how roles work, you will need to remove this module and add your own HttpModule to handle authorization.  UrlAuthorizationModule's source code is readily available so it's actually a fairly simple matter of creating an HttpModule that works similar.